# JavaScript Setting property of a disabled button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, document-ready

**PRE EDIT:** It turned out that it was not about the disability of the button, but making some other actions after save. I debugged the page and found out that after making changes on a saved form, then page loses the javascript functionality in the `(document).ready` part. I've added the solution as an answer.

---

I have an entry page which has two buttons save and approve. The mechanism is something like, you can fill the form and save, then approve. You can also reach a saved page by refreshing the page or from the list of your saved pages.

The approve button is disabled if the form is not saved. I enable it from code behind after saving. Approve button also has a confirm button extender which takes its confirm text from javascript. I load it in `(document).ready` and its code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ASPxSplitter1_ContentPlaceHolder1_uctActivityEntry1_tbActivity_tbHistory_btnApproveActivity_btnApprove").click(function () {

            $("#ASPxSplitter1_ContentPlaceHolder1_uctActivityEntry1_tbActivity_tbHistory_btnApproveActivity_lblMessage").text(GetConfirmTextForApprove());
        });
    });
```

,where `GetConfirmTextForApproval()` makes some calculations and returns the confirm text.

Now, my problem is, as the button is disabled when you open the form, the code above is not rendered at the first page load. This leads to the problem that, when I start to fill a form and save it, then approve it, I don't get any confirm text, because it does not run the function. But after refreshing the page or after I go to a saved form's page from another page, I get the proper confirm text.

So, how can I solve this problem? How can I get the proper confirm text even though the button is disabled at the first page load?

Note: I have to add that after saving, the url of the page is changed. The query string is added. That might also cause the problem.

Comment: ... **wow** those ID names are massive. Ever consider using classes?

Comment: the code above is not rendered at the first page load... so make the code being rendered

Comment: @Doorknob It's because using so many user controls. The button and the page is a user control.

Comment: @lavrik My question is "How to make it rendered?" =)

Comment: Add the <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/youFile.js"/> tag on the target page. Place you code into /scripts/youFile.js and it should run.

Comment: @lavrik What is the difference between putting it in the head or putting it in another source file? The reason for not being rendered is that, it is not enabled.

Comment: In your case it doesn;t matter where to include you script i think, but if you manually inlcude it on the page - it will work, but if you render it with some asp.net web forms mechanizm - i can't help you, didn't use it for ages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
// Disable #x
$( "#x" ).prop( "disabled", true );

// Enable #x
$( "#x" ).prop( "disabled", false );
```

But not when document ready, you need enable button when you want. Then you need create a event listener

```
$("#button").click(function(){
  //Your code

  if(GetConfirmTextForApproval()){
  //You active the button and the text that you want show.
   }
});
```

Comment: I can't use click event, because it's triggered after the confirm pop-up. That is, when I use the click event listener, it first shows the popup and after I click "yes" in the popup, then it changes the text of the popup, which is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem:

As it was said in the pre edit of the question, the problem was caused because of making changes after the save. I've changed my function as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    SetConfirmMessageForApproval();
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
});

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    SetConfirmMessageForApproval();
    }

function SetConfirmMessageForApproval() {
        $("#ASPxSplitter1_ContentPlaceHolder1_uctActivityEntry1_tbActivity_tbHistory_btnApproveActivity_btnApprove").click(function () {
            $("#ASPxSplitter1_ContentPlaceHolder1_uctActivityEntry1_tbActivity_tbHistory_btnApproveActivity_lblMessage").text(GetConfirmTextForApprove());
        });
    }
```

This helps, if anyone else needs it.